# why this statement 'This field is required.' keep displays in my webpage

Tags: html, django, model

[my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBhaM.png)

why that statement keep displays in my webpage?,i created this webpage using django

my html:

```
 <form method ='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value = "Search">
</form>

<form method="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{forms}}

    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import EbookModel

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    pdf_title=forms.CharField(label='pdf_title',max_length=100)

class UploadPdf(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=EbookModel
        fields=('title','pdf',)
```

Comment: <form method="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}

    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form> Remove the s in the {{forms}}

Comment: Show your EbookModel here

Comment: @fakeMake this is my EbookModel: class EbookModel(models.Model):
 title=models.CharField(max_length=60)
 pdf=models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs/',blank=True)

 class Meta(object):
  ordering=['title']
 def __str__(self):
  return f"{self.title}"

Comment: So that answer has not worked for you??

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}

    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

Try and see if this solves your problem.